# Merge multiple for loop in JAVA Generic method

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming, generic-list

I'm currently modifying a senior project, but im still a newbie in JAVA. I tried to search for alot of information about generic method and applied, but they seem to be incorrect. Please help me and take a look and correct me where I'm wrong. Thank you. =)

Below is the code I tried to use for the generic method to merge the for loop.

```
public String[] name = {
 "SDLManPower sdlManPower",
 "SDLScopeOfWork sdlSOW",
 "SDLMaterial sdlMat",
 "SDLUtility sdlUtil",
 "SDLTMEquip sdlTMEquip"
};

public String[] sname = {
 "sdlManPower",
 "sdlSOW",
 "sdlMat",
 "sdlUtil",
 "sdlTMEquip"
};

public String[] list = {
 "getAttendanceList()",
 "getSowList()",
 "SDLMaterial sdlMat",
 "getUtilityList()",
 "getEquipmentList()"
};

public String[] forlp = {
 "(SDLManPower manPower : sdlManPowerList",
 "SDLScopeOfWork sow : sdlSOWList",
 "SDLMaterial projectMat : sdlMaterialList",
 "SDLUtility utility : sdlUtilityList",
 "SDLTMEquip sdlEquipment : sdlEquipmentList"
};

public String[] id = {
 "getUserUID()",
 "getSubTreatmentID()",
 "getPurposeID()",
 "getUtilityID()",
 "getSubEquipmentID()"
};

public String[] fname = {
 "manPower",
 "sow",
 "projectMat",
 "utility",
 "sdlEquipment"
};


public static < T > void AllList(T[] name, T[] sname, T[] list, T[] forlp, T[] id, T[] fname) {

 for (T x: name) {
  for (name[x]: sdlReportObj.list[x]) {
   Boolean alreadyExist = true;
   for (forlp[x]) {
    if (sname[x].id[x] == fname[x].id[x] && sname[x].getProjectTeamUID().equals(fname[x].getProjectTeamUID())) {
     alreadyExist = true;
     break;
    } else {
     alreadyExist = false;
    }
   }
   if (!alreadyExist) {

    UserGroup user = null;
    Vendor v = null;
    ProjectArrangement[] arrangementList = projectInfo.getProjPlan().getArrangementList();
    for (ProjectArrangement projArrangement: arrangementList) {
     if (projArrangement.getuID().equals(sname[x].getProjectTeamUID())) {

      if (projArrangement.getUserGroupUID() != null) {
       user = userList.getUserGroupCollection().findUserGroup(projArrangement.getUserGroupUID());
      } else {
       v = (Vendor) maintData.getVendorCollection().findItem(projArrangement.getVendorID());
      }
     }
    }

    sname[x].setTeamName(user != null ? user.getRoleFullName() : v.getName());
    sname[x].setUserGroupID(user != null ? user.getRoleUID() : v.getId() + "");
    sname[x].setDeletable(true);
    sname[x].setValue(0.00);
    sname[x].setPreLoad(false);
    sdlEquipmentList.add(sdlTMEquip);
   }
  }
 } //for name
}
```

The code below is senior work. He used many for loops to do a similar action.
So I would like to use a generic method to reduce the system loading time by merging all the for loops into one. But I have failed. =(

```
if (sdlReportObj != null && sdlReportObj.getProjectUID().equals(projectInfo.getProjectUID())) {
 for (SDLExpenses sdlExpenses: sdlReportObj.getExpensesList()) {
  Boolean alreadyExist = true;
  for (ProjectExpenses projExpenses: projectInfo.getProjPlan().getExpensesList()) {
   if (projExpenses.getExpensesItemID() == sdlExpenses.getSubExpensesItemID()) {
    alreadyExist = true;
    break;
   } else {
    alreadyExist = false;
   }
  }
  if (!alreadyExist || projectInfo.getProjPlan().getExpensesList().length == 0) {

   sdlExpenses.setDeletable(true);
   sdlExpenses.setValue(0.00);
   sdlExpenses.setPreLoad(false);
   sdlExpensesList.add(sdlExpenses);
  }
 }

 for (SDLManPower sdlManPower: sdlReportObj.getAttendanceList()) {
  Boolean alreadyExist = true;
  for (SDLManPower manPower: sdlManPowerList) {
   if (manPower.getUserUID().equals(sdlManPower.getUserUID()) && sdlManPower.getProjectTeamUID().equals(manPower.getProjectTeamUID())) {
    alreadyExist = true;
    break;
   } else {
    alreadyExist = false;
   }
  }
  if (!alreadyExist) {
   // tempManPower.setDeletable(false);
   UserGroup user = null;
   Vendor v = null;
   ProjectArrangement[] arrangementList = projectInfo.getProjPlan().getArrangementList();
   for (ProjectArrangement projArrangement: arrangementList) {
    if (projArrangement.getuID().equals(sdlManPower.getProjectTeamUID())) {

     if (projArrangement.getUserGroupUID() != null) {
      user = userList.getUserGroupCollection().findUserGroup(projArrangement.getUserGroupUID());
     } else {
      v = (Vendor) maintData.getVendorCollection().findItem(projArrangement.getVendorID());
     }
    }
   }

   sdlManPower.setTeamName(user != null ? user.getRoleFullName() : v.getName());
   sdlManPower.setUserGroupID(user != null ? user.getRoleUID() : v.getId() + "");
   sdlManPower.setStartTime(null);
   sdlManPower.setEndTime(null);
   sdlManPower.setPreLoad(false);
   sdlManPowerList.add(sdlManPower);
  }
 }


 ArrayList < SDLScopeOfWork > tempSOWList = new ArrayList < SDLScopeOfWork > ();
 for (SDLScopeOfWork sdlSOW: sdlReportObj.getSowList()) { //foreach sow in sdl
  Boolean alreadyExist = true;

  for (SDLScopeOfWork sow: sdlSOWList) {
   if (sdlSOW.getSubTreatmentID() == sow.getSubTreatmentID() && sdlSOW.getProjectTeamUID().equals(sow.getProjectTeamUID())) { //
    alreadyExist = true;
    break;
   } else {
    alreadyExist = false;
    tempSOWList.add(sow);
   }
  }

  if (!alreadyExist) {
   UserGroup user = null;
   Vendor v = null;
   ProjectArrangement[] arrangementList = projectInfo.getProjPlan().getArrangementList();
   for (ProjectArrangement projArrangement: arrangementList) {
    if (projArrangement.getuID().equals(sdlSOW.getProjectTeamUID())) {

     if (projArrangement.getUserGroupUID() != null) {
      user = userList.getUserGroupCollection().findUserGroup(projArrangement.getUserGroupUID());
     } else {
      v = (Vendor) maintData.getVendorCollection().findItem(projArrangement.getVendorID());
     }
    }
   }

   sdlSOW.setTeamName(user != null ? user.getRoleFullName() : v.getName());
   sdlSOW.setUserGroupID(user != null ? user.getRoleUID() : v.getId() + "");
   sdlSOW.setDeletable(true);
   sdlSOW.setFrom(0.00);
   sdlSOW.setTo(0.00);
   sdlSOW.setValue(0.00);
   sdlSOW.setPreLoad(false);

   sdlSOWList.add(sdlSOW);
  }
 }
 //sdlSOWList.addAll(tempSOWList);

 for (SDLMaterial sdlMat: sdlReportObj.SDLMaterial sdlMat) {
  Boolean alreadyExist = true;
  for (SDLMaterial projectMat: sdlMaterialList) {
   if (sdlMat.getPurposeID() == projectMat.getPurposeID() && sdlMat.getProjectTeamUID().equals(projectMat.getProjectTeamUID())) {
    alreadyExist = true;
    break;
   } else {
    alreadyExist = false;
   }
  }
  if (!alreadyExist) {
   UserGroup user = null;
   Vendor v = null;
   ProjectArrangement[] arrangementList = projectInfo.getProjPlan().getArrangementList();
   for (ProjectArrangement projArrangement: arrangementList) {
    if (projArrangement.getuID().equals(sdlMat.getProjectTeamUID())) {

     if (projArrangement.getUserGroupUID() != null) {
      user = userList.getUserGroupCollection().findUserGroup(projArrangement.getUserGroupUID());
     } else {
      v = (Vendor) maintData.getVendorCollection().findItem(projArrangement.getVendorID());
     }
    }
   }

   sdlMat.setTeamName(user != null ? user.getRoleFullName() : v.getName());
   sdlMat.setUserGroupID(user != null ? user.getRoleUID() : v.getId() + "");
   sdlMat.setDeletable(true);
   sdlMat.setValue(0.00);
   sdlMat.setPreLoad(false);

   sdlMaterialList.add(sdlMat);
  }
 }

 for (SDLUtility sdlUtil: sdlReportObj.getUtilityList()) { // a,b,d,c
  Boolean alreadyExist = true;

  for (SDLUtility utility: sdlUtilityList) { // a,b,c
   if (sdlUtil.getUtilityID() == utility.getUtilityID() && sdlUtil.getProjectTeamUID().equals(utility.getProjectTeamUID())) {
    alreadyExist = true;
    break;
   } else {
    alreadyExist = false;
   }
  }

  if (!alreadyExist) {
   UserGroup user = null;
   Vendor v = null;
   ProjectArrangement[] arrangementList = projectInfo.getProjPlan().getArrangementList();
   for (ProjectArrangement projArrangement: arrangementList) {
    if (projArrangement.getuID().equals(sdlUtil.getProjectTeamUID())) {

     if (projArrangement.getUserGroupUID() != null) {
      user = userList.getUserGroupCollection().findUserGroup(projArrangement.getUserGroupUID());
     } else {
      v = (Vendor) maintData.getVendorCollection().findItem(projArrangement.getVendorID());
     }
    }
   }

   sdlUtil.setTeamName(user != null ? user.getRoleFullName() : v.getName());
   sdlUtil.setUserGroupID(user != null ? user.getRoleUID() : v.getId() + "");
   sdlUtil.setDeletable(true);
   sdlUtil.setRegistrationNo(null);
   sdlUtil.setValue(0.00);
   sdlUtil.setPreLoad(false);
   sdlUtilityList.add(sdlUtil);
  }
 }

 // tm equip
 for (SDLTMEquip sdlTMEquip: sdlReportObj.getEquipmentList()) {
  Boolean alreadyExist = true;
  for (SDLTMEquip sdlEquipment: sdlEquipmentList) {
   if (sdlTMEquip.getSubEquipmentID() == sdlEquipment.getSubEquipmentID() && sdlTMEquip.getProjectTeamUID().equals(sdlEquipment.getProjectTeamUID())) {
    alreadyExist = true;
    break;
   } else {
    alreadyExist = false;
   }
  }
  if (!alreadyExist) {

   UserGroup user = null;
   Vendor v = null;
   ProjectArrangement[] arrangementList = projectInfo.getProjPlan().getArrangementList();
   for (ProjectArrangement projArrangement: arrangementList) {
    if (projArrangement.getuID().equals(sdlTMEquip.getProjectTeamUID())) {

     if (projArrangement.getUserGroupUID() != null) {
      user = userList.getUserGroupCollection().findUserGroup(projArrangement.getUserGroupUID());
     } else {
      v = (Vendor) maintData.getVendorCollection().findItem(projArrangement.getVendorID());
     }
    }
   }

   sdlTMEquip.setTeamName(user != null ? user.getRoleFullName() : v.getName());
   sdlTMEquip.setUserGroupID(user != null ? user.getRoleUID() : v.getId() + "");
   sdlTMEquip.setDeletable(true);
   sdlTMEquip.setValue(0.00);
   sdlTMEquip.setPreLoad(false);
   sdlEquipmentList.add(sdlTMEquip);
  }
 }
```

Is it possible to use a generic method to reduce the loading time and number of loops?
Is there another ways to solve it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first, it looks like your senior just puked in the ide and does that same thing by copy/paste of previous lines. So please do not copy his work because he calls himself a senior. I speak from bad experience.

So yes, you could do a refactoring into somethink like Generics. But it is not the answer to your problem. The answer is: Just divide the problem in smaller, more handier problems.

SDLExpenses, SDLScopeOfWork, SDLMaterial, SDLUtility and SDLTMEquip should have an common Interface, name it SDLIntf and you should implement 5 new classes with this Interface.
Use a Abstract Factory (https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-abstract-factory) to get an new Instance of the class, depending on the type, you return the Product. I.E. sdlReportObj.SDLMaterial you return a new SDLMaterial object.

Every Class has the same Methods which are defined in SDLIntf, lets call it SortData(), and here is the work you should do. If you use for loops, ok. But if you use Java 8, try to get firm with Lambda Expressions. With that, every for loop and if could be replaced with one line of code. But if you use Java 5 to 7, stick to the foreach loop your senior is using, its nothing wrong about it.

It would be too much work to explain the complete refactored classes, but my code would look like:

```
if (sdlReportObj != null && sdlReportObj.getProjectUID().equals(projectInfo.getProjectUID())) {
    SDLIntf mat = SDLFactory.GetProduct(sdlMat, projectInfo);
    SDLIntf sdlSOW = SDLFactory.GetProduct(sdlReportObj.getSowList(), projectInfo);

    mat.SortData();
    sdlSOW.SortData();
    ... etc......
}
```

So at the end you should access the data and do something with it. But only you know what it should do. And best thing is, you could Unit Test the whole think pretty easy.

And yes, you could run private methods in your classes for even smaller problems like in SDLScopeOfWork, I see potential for at least 4 small methods with way more readable code. To be honest, I even I have some trouble understanding why he is using multiple for loops.

Just a fast think I have done in Notepad++ (no Java IDE on this machine ;) ) -> https://pastebin.com/qkFHAb4J

Maybe this gives you the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i have a right direction to complete it.